# jQuery mobile reloads page. Behaviour not expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-mobile

I have a setup with jQuery mobile and another systems. On one page I need to show an ajax loaded dialog and return data to the main page depending on the link clicked (with class `link`).

```
$(document).live("pageinit", function(event) {
    $(document).on("click", ".link", function (event) {
                putDataToTheMainPage();

                $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');

                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            });
});
```

But the plugin doesn't close the dialog, It behaves the same way as clicking a normal link. I know the function is executed when the click event fires, but the execution of other handlers (the ones that jQuery mobile provides) continues. What is happening here?

Neither this handler function for links nor the close button that jquery mobile adds automatically to the header work correctly when the page containing the link to the dialog is loaded using jquery mobile BUT **the page does work as expected when loaded using the URL to it or is reloaded using the browser**.

More context:
The dialog is loaded using a normal dialog link.

```
<a href="link.html" class="class" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop"><img src="button.gif"></a>
```

I'm using the following structure for the page which draws the dialog.

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" class="content" role="main">
            <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false" role="banner">
                  <div class="myheaderdiv"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                  <ul>
                       <li>link, text and images</li>
                       <li>link, text and images</li>
                         ...
                  </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your HTML, or at least HTML for your dialog? Just so we can get a context of your problem.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation` or `event.preventDefault` should be the first thing you do inside an event handler. You could also try `event.stopImmediatePropagation`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases when the dialog('close') function doesn´t work I use the following instructions to go back or go to my home screen:

```
window.history.back();
```

or

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#home"));
```

home -> is my main page

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block event handlers from firing then you have to stop them at the right time. I have made an example below, but unfortunatly it does not work on IE 8 and below.

http://jsfiddle.net/CXMcN/4/

html:

```
<a class="link">you can stop me from bubbling</a>
<br />
<br />
<a>but you can't stop me</a>
```

javascript with jquery:

```
$('a').on('click' , function(event) {

    alert('hello world');

});

//reference for last target link element that had an mousedown event
var mousedownEl;

//set this flag to be true if we want to 
//stop click event from bubbling down from body
var mouseClickOnLink = false;

$('a.link').on('mousedown', function() {

    mousedownEl = this;    

});

$('a.link').on('mouseup', function() {

    //if the element that last triggered mouse down is this
    //then a click event will occur after the mouseup 
    //event and we set the flag to cancel the click event
    if(mousedownEl == this) {             
        mouseClickOnLink = true;    
    }

});


//add click event listener for body in the capture phase
// http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html
// (jquery does not support event capture phase argument 
//  so you might need to add some browser compability code
//  for adding the event handler correctly in different browsers)
$('body')[0].addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() {                

        //if mouse click flag is set to true 
        //prevent event from bubbling
        if(mouseClickOnLink)
        {            

            //stop event from bubbling further down in the dom
            //and firing their event handlers
            event.stopPropagation();            

            //reset flag
            mouseClickOnLink = false;

        }

    },
    true); //add event handler at capture phase
```